# Determine $n$ in the equality $1+2(2!)+3(3!)+…+n(n!)=719$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Determine $n$ in equality: $1+2(2!)+3(3!)+…+n(n!)=719$.(Answer:5)

I tried to separate the terms but I didn't succeed

$  1+2(2!)+3.3(2!)+4.4.3(2!)+\ldots+n.n((n-1)!)=719\\ 2!(2+3^2+4^2.3+5^2.4.3\ldots)+n^2((n-1)!)=718$

Comment: See what happens when you write each summand $kk!$ as $[(k+1)-1]k!=(k+1)!-k!$.

Comment: @AnneBauval  I don't understand how he arrived at this equality: $ \sum_{n = 1}^{N} n\cdot n! = (1 + N)! - 1$

Comment: Just sum up the equality of the accepted answer (which is the same as owl's hint above): it gives you a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k = 1}^n{k\cdot k!} &= \sum_{k = 1}^n{\left[(k+1) - 1\right]\cdot k!} = \sum_{k = 1}^n{\left[(k+1)\cdot k! - k!\right]} = \sum_{k = 1}^n{\left[(k+1)! - k!\right]} = \\
&= \left[2!-1!\right] + \left[3!-2!\right] + \ldots + \left[(n-1)!-(n-2)!\right] + \left[n!-(n-1)!\right] + \left[(n+1)!-n!\right] = \\
&= \left[\color{blue}{2!}-1!\right] + \left[\color{red}{3!}-\color{blue}{2!}\right] + \ldots + \left[\color{blue}{(n-1)!}-\color{red}{(n-2)!}\right] + \left[\color{green}{n!}-\color{blue}{(n-1)!}\right] + \left[(n+1)!-\color{green}{n!}\right] = \\ 
&= \left[\text{all the colored terms are canceled out}\right] = \\
&= (n+1)!-1 = 719 \Leftrightarrow (n+1)! = 720 \Rightarrow n = \ldots
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, the easy way and the hard way.

Obviously 719 = 6!-1. 5 * 5! is a bit smaller than 6!. Your guess is that the sum up to n(n!) equals (n+1)!-1, you prove that by induction, then you have (n+1)! = 720, n+1 = 6, n = 5.

Or you just add 1, $2*2!=4$, $3*3!=18$, $4*4!=96$, $5*5!$ = 600, the total is 719, so n= 5.

People will disagree which is the easy and which is the hard way.